# Use my Validation function as in import React

Tags: reactjs, function, export

I have a function sitting inside my signup code, but I would like to have it as an import so I can call the validation on other pages as well. I seem to be having some issues with getting the import to work and not sure what I'm missing.

Here is the code as it's currently in my signup form:

```
const onChangeValidation = (dataValues = formData) => {
    let testData = { ...errors };

    if ('firstName' in dataValues)
        testData.firstName =
            dataValues.firstName.length > 1
                ? ''
                : 'Please enter a valid name.';

    if ('password' in dataValues)
        testData.password =
            dataValues.password.length > 9
                ? ''
                : 'Password must be a minimum of 10 characters';

    setErrors({ ...testData });

    if (dataValues === formData)
        return Object.values(testData).every((x) => x === '');
};

const validation = (dataValues = formData) => {
    let testData = { ...errors };

    if ('email' in dataValues)
        testData.email = /$^|.+@+..+/.test(dataValues.email)
            ? ''
            : 'Email is not valid';

    testData.email2 =
        dataValues.email === dataValues.email2
            ? ''
            : 'Emails do not match!';

    testData.password2 =
        dataValues.password === dataValues.password2
            ? ''
            : 'Passwords do not match!';

    setErrors({ ...testData });

    if (dataValues === formData)
        return Object.values(testData).every((x) => x === '');
};
```

Now once I move these two functions to a new folder under components/validation it looks like this:

```
export function validation() {
let testData = { ...errors };

if ('email' in dataValues)
    testData.email = /$^|.+@+..+/.test(dataValues.email)
        ? ''
        : 'Email is not valid';

testData.email2 =
    dataValues.email === dataValues.email2 ? '' : 'Emails do not match!';

testData.password2 =
    dataValues.password === dataValues.password2
        ? ''
        : 'Passwords do not match!';

setErrors({ ...testData });

if (dataValues === formData)
    return Object.values(testData).every((x) => x === '');
```

}

export function onChangeValidation() {
let testData = { ...errors };

```
if ('firstName' in dataValues)
    testData.firstName =
        dataValues.firstName.length > 1 ? '' : 'Please enter a valid name.';

if ('password' in dataValues)
    testData.password =
        dataValues.password.length > 9
            ? ''
            : 'Password must be a minimum of 10 characters';

setErrors({ ...testData });

if (dataValues === formData)
    return Object.values(testData).every((x) => x === '');
```

}

Now I get the error that dataValues, formData, errors and setErrors is not defined....once I add them though it doesn't change anything as I still can't just call the functions in my signup form

I use import { validation, onChangeValidation } from '../../components/validation';

and try to run my functions, but I'm not sure what params I should pass....can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `validation` works with `dataValues` but this variable is not defined. Just pass it to the function like: `function validation(dateValues) {...}`. The same stays for the second function and all missing variables.

P.S. As you see, before you passed `dataValues` to the functions:

```
const validation = (dataValues = formData) => {...}
```